# Unable to build docker image due to failed to process "${project.artifactId}": missing ':' in substitution

Tags: maven, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image for a maven project with the command: `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pdocker`

I have the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG serviceuser=${project.artifactId}

##UPDATES AND INSTALL REQUIRED PACKAGES
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gettext-base sudo && \
    apt-get install -y iptables sudo && \
    adduser --shell /bin/bash ${serviceuser} && \
    adduser ${serviceuser} sudo && \
    echo "%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER ${serviceuser}

##MOVE AND COPY PROJECT FILES INTO CONTAINER
COPY ${project.build.finalName}.jar /home/${serviceuser}/

WORKDIR /home/${serviceuser}
```

The **pom.xml** file has some of the following contents: (Have made it shorter just for explaination)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.book.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>book-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>book-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>docker</id>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>docker</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build</goal>
                  <goal>push</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <contextDirectory>${project.build.directory}</contextDirectory>
              <repository>test-img:2000/v1/${project.artifactId}</repository>
              <tag>${project.version}</tag>
              <tag>latest</tag>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

When i build, it gives me the following error message...

Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: failed to process "${project.artifactId}": missing ':' in substitution

[ERROR] failed to process **"${project.artifactId}": missing ':' in substitution**

**[INFO] BUILD FAILURE**

I would appreciate any hints or help, thank you.

Comment: I recommend to simply set the `<finalName>..</finalName>` in your pom file and just define the name in your Dockerfile instead of trying to filter it...

Comment: The final name would change every so often when version bumps up. So I can't hard-code value in Dockerfile

Comment: Simply wrong...I wrote set the final name like `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` so you have no version in that name anymore... and can be used in `Dockerfile`...

Comment: @khmarbaise - Sure I think you may be onto something. Can you guide me a little more please. So under which block do I specify `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` in the pom.xml file. Will it be under <build></build> as plugin? And what exactly will be the change in Dockerfile. You may use the current example. Would appreciate it, thanks. Sorry for asking again!

Comment: No Problem see my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Docker throws this misleading error whenever you have certain non alpha-numeric characters in your variable name.

I assume that it is trying to interpret them as syntax to specify bash style [default value substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

To prevent this error, remove the character from your variable name.

In your example it is the `.` causing the error, for me it was a `-` which I had to replace with an `_`.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I don't have the option to remove the period(".") as it is part of a property string. is there any way I can escape the period??

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this when the ARG is not defined in the dockerfile.  You can define your value as:

```
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG ARTIFACT_ID
```

Then in your maven configuration, you will define the argument passed to the build as such:

```
<buildArgs>
   <JAR_FILE>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</JAR_FILE>
   <ARTIFACT_ID>${project.artifactId}</ARTIFACT_ID>
</buildArgs>
```

You can then reference those in your dockerfile as such:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

#Defined by the Maven Build Arguments in POM File
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG ARTIFACT_ID

# Add Maven dependencies (not shaded into the artifact; Docker-cached)
ADD target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib      /usr/share/${ARTIFACT_ID}/lib
ADD target/dependency/META-INF          /usr/share/${ARTIFACT_ID}/META-INF
ADD target/dependency/BOOT-INF/classes  /usr/share/${ARTIFACT_ID}

# Add the service itself
ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /usr/share/${ARTIFACT_ID}/${JAR_FILE}

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "/usr/share/${ARTIFACT_ID}/${JAR_FILE}"]
```

Your final POM Plugin would look something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>push</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        <tag>${project.version}</tag>       
        <buildArgs>
            <JAR_FILE>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</JAR_FILE>
            <ARTIFACT_ID>${project.artifactId}</ARTIFACT_ID>
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `<finalName>..</finalName>` in your pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.book.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>book-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>book-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>docker</id>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>docker</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>build</goal>
                  <goal>push</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <contextDirectory>${project.build.directory}</contextDirectory>
              <repository>test-img:2000/v1/${project.artifactId}</repository>
              <tag>${project.version}</tag>
              <tag>latest</tag>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

afterwards you can use in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ARG serviceuser=${project.artifactId}

##UPDATES AND INSTALL REQUIRED PACKAGES
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gettext-base sudo && \
    apt-get install -y iptables sudo && \
    adduser --shell /bin/bash ${serviceuser} && \
    adduser ${serviceuser} sudo && \
    echo "%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER ${serviceuser}

##MOVE AND COPY PROJECT FILES INTO CONTAINER
COPY target/book-app.jar /home/${serviceuser}/

WORKDIR /home/${serviceuser}
```

I'm not sure why you use `serviceuser` as an ARG for the Dockerfile..

You can read in the documentation for the pom.xml: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Hi again - So I tried exactly what you said and still see the same error. 
`${project.artifactId}": missing ':' in substitution` :(